apt: How to properly `autoremove` redundant, auto-installed dependencies?
I have a Apt configuration file at /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99recommends-and-suggests, containing:
APT::Install-Recommends "true";
APT::Install-Suggests "false";
APT::AutoRemove::RecommendsImportant "true";
APT::AutoRemove::SuggestsImportant "false";

For example, apt-cache depends inxi shows:
inxi
  Depends: pciutils
  Depends: procps
  Depends: <perl:any>
    perl
  Recommends: dmidecode
  Recommends: dnsutils
    bind9-dnsutils
  Recommends: file
 |Recommends: iproute2
  Recommends: net-tools
  Recommends: kmod
  Recommends: lm-sensors
  Recommends: mesa-utils
 |Recommends: sudo
    sudo-ldap
  Recommends: doas
    opendoas
  Recommends: tree
  Recommends: usbutils
  Recommends: x11-utils
  Recommends: x11-xserver-utils
  Suggests: libxml-dumper-perl
 |Suggests: wget
 |Suggests: curl
  Suggests: libhttp-tiny-perl
    perl

The above output indicates the package inxi depends on the "recommended" iproute2 package, but net-tools can also replace it.
apt-cache depends --installed inxi after apt install -y inxi:
inxi
  Depends: pciutils
  Depends: procps
  Recommends: dmidecode
  Recommends: file
 |Recommends: iproute2
  Recommends: kmod
  Recommends: lm-sensors
  Recommends: mesa-utils
 |Recommends: sudo
    sudo-ldap
  Recommends: tree
  Recommends: usbutils
  Recommends: x11-utils
  Recommends: x11-xserver-utils
 |Suggests: wget
 |Suggests: curl

This shows that apt has selected to install iproute2 instead of net-tools, as auto-installed package.
At this stage, if I do:
apt install -y net-tools && apt-mark auto net-tools

apt autoremove will not remove net-tools as it is the dependency for inxi, even if iproute2 is present.
For this kind of problems, is there a way to autoremove the redundant, auto-installed dependencies (for Depends, Recommends, and Suggests)?

Does this answer your question? How to remove recommended and suggested dependencies of uninstalled packages?

@vanadium This does not cover what the above question is talking about.
